# How can I determine what revision of source code is on my PC?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Until now I used SVN for couple of years.
I converted my code management to TFS.

In SVN I had an option to see history of commits and the current local version of the code was marked in bold black.(by revision's)

How can I determine what revision of source code is on my PC?

Comment: What do you mean by "full update"?

Comment: Get all changes from the TFS server

Comment: So you want to see what version of the source code is on your local machine?

Comment: Yes... What is the changeset number(version number like revision in SVN)

Answer (score 2):

In the Source Control explorer you can check the properties of a file, this panel will show the Workspace version, which is the number you're after.

Since different files can be at different versions, there is no indicator which shows the workspace version of all files in your workspace. Some files can be at latest, while others may have been fetched using "Get specific version" or may not have been updated recently.

[image]

[image]

or from the Commandline:

```
 2013:\> tf localversions path\to\file
 2015:\> tf vc localversions path\to\file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see ServerName and Latest Version numbers but "Local Name" , "Workspace Version" and "Encoding" are marked as "Not applicable". What is the reason and how can I solve this?

Comment: Is the file in question present in the workspace on disk?